# Error while trying to install Node, and its related programs, and apparently because I can't get TLS 1.2 support in Windows 7

Tags: node.js, powershell, windows-7, tls1.2, chocolatey

I tried to install Node, plus any extra tools it optionally 'needs' which apparently included "Chocolatey".

("Chocolatey" is a poorly named package manager. The developer of it saw that Visual Studio IDE has NuGet, he thought it'd be good if Windows had a package manager, just as unix-based OSs have package managers like debian has apt-get or osx has brew and macports, and he made one for windows called - "Chocolatey" as his joke, and it has some growing amount of software it supports. e.g. I see you can do `choco install vlc` to install VLC media player.  I don't know what software Node would use it to install but anyhow)

I tried to install Node and I think I ticked the box for it to install other software that it needs. It required me to close all my programs, which I did.

I got this error during the install

[image]

I searched that error "Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1""

And I got this https://chocolatey.org/docs/troubleshooting

"If you see the following: Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel." then you are likely running an older machine that needs to be upgraded to be able to use TLS 1.2 at a minimum."

I find that strange, since TLS 1.2 was released a long while back as seen on this page.  https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/tls-vs-ssl/  TLS 1.2 was released in 2008.  I'd be surprised if Windows 7 doesn't support it, since Windows 7 only reached end of life Jan 2020. Even TLS 1.3 was released in 2018.

When searching the error, I found this page https://support.cybersource.com/s/article/How-do-I-enable-TLS-1-2-on-Windows-7

It mentioned certain registry keys that it says I needed.

According to https://chocolatey.org/blog/remove-support-for-old-tls-versions

> ```
> While your operating system may support TLS 1.2 it's important to remember that it may have to be enabled. If you are working from
> ```
>
> PowerShell you can find out which protocols your system supports by
>   running this code:
>
> ```
> [Enum]::GetNames([Net.SecurityProtocolType]) -contains 'Tls12'
> Copy
> If the result is True then your system supports TLS 1.2.
> ```

And it then goes on to say if it is supported how to check if it is being used.

But for me

TLS 1.2 shows as not supported

```
PS C:\Users\User>  [Enum]::GetNames([Net.SecurityProtocolType]) -contains 'Tls12'
False
```

I saw this page https://support.cybersource.com/s/article/How-do-I-enable-TLS-1-2-on-Windows-7

And made this reg file

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00



[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Client]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.1\Server]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000
```

I notice I have a key (folder on the left hand side), in regedit called SSL 2.0   Not sure what, if anything, should be in there

I tried restarting but still running the mentioned powershell command gave false, indicating TLS 1.2 not supported.

Comment: I have another comp with windows 7 that is currently disassembled so I can't check it now but I don't think I got such an error with that. Also,years ago I used a portable version of node no install required, so I may try that kind of thing though not sure what I might lose out on if doing that. I could also try installing node without ticking the box for insatlling the other stuff

Comment: Is your Windows 7 machine up to date with respect to Windows updates and _has its PowerShell version been updated_? An up-to-date Windows 7 machine _with PowerShell 5.1_ should report `$true` for `[Enum]::GetNames([Net.SecurityProtocolType]) -contains 'Tls12'`. Check `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion`

Comment: @mklement0 ah thanks,  I think you are onto something.. I  notice my powershell is old, version 2. I got an error just now trying to update powershell so yeah my powershell is old.. And what you say makes sense 'cos from what I recall, I had no problem installing node on win7 on another machine. So I will focus on trying to get the latest powershell installed.

Answer (score 0):

You need add these values to yours register keys:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -Type DWord 

Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -Type DWord
```

They were took from *Sanjeev Kumar*'s answer in [node.js installation error in windows 10 in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62620249/node-js-installation-error-in-windows-10-in-vscode)
... and worked for me.