# NodeJs/Powershell download issue

Tags: node.js, powershell

Trying to download NODEJS v12 or v13 on windows7 laptop, installation procedure went well but on 'Windows Powershell' I am getting this error:

```
"Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "Unable to connect to the remote server"
At line:1 char:1"
```

Anyone able to help me with this?

[image]

Comment: remove `iex`  (`Invoke-Expression`)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [node.js installation error in windows 10 in vscode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62620249/node-js-installation-error-in-windows-10-in-vscode)

Comment: See *pauby* and *Sanjeev Kumar*'s answers in:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62620249/node-js-installation-error-in-windows-10-in-vscode